# Customize Markdown output from docx using pandoc

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc, mathml, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to convert docx to markdown using pandoc, but I am unable to figure out how to override specific cases while converting to markdown using pandoc.

I am using command

```
pandoc -s --mathml Sample.docx -t markdown_github -o example50.md
```

But the equations output is still coming in the form of **latex** and not **MathMl**

The equation output is of the form

```
$$\\text{Torque}\\left( N \\times m \\right) = Inertia\\ \\left( kg \\times m^{2} \\right) \\times Acceleration\\left( \\frac{\\text{rad}}{\\sec^{2}} \\right)$$
```

> I want to override some other markdown using my custom Markdown
>   Grammar which.

Any help will be appreciated. Any other libraries or sources can also be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting to markdown and the `--mathml` option is only for HTML output.

[Math in Pandoc Markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#math) is basically LaTeX Math between dollar signs.

Comment: Yes i read it in the doc --mathml is not supported for docx, but i want to convert equations it to mathml,

Is it possible to customize my markdown, I have read filters, but they modify the value and not the end conversion.

Comment: yes, with [pandoc filters](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) you can modify the document AST. so there you could change the _math_ parts to normal text or _raw html_ before it's rendered to markdown by the markdown writer.